# How to read the coloned attribute names (Eg. model:name) while parsing xml using XmlSlurper

Tags: xml, grails, groovy, xmlslurper

I have an XMl where an attribute is e.g. model:name.

After upgrading to Grails 2, it fails to extract the attribute using

it.@"model:name".text()

I have read [How to read the hyphenated attribute names (Eg. model_name) while parsing xml using XmlSlurper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736636/how-to-read-the-hyphenated-attribute-names-eg-model-name-while-parsing-xml-us) and followed the links too, but nothing points me towards documentation on how to handle coloned attributes.

**Final solution for xml:lang attributes:**
it.attributes()['{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you refer to as a "coloned attribute" is actually an attribute that is in a *namespace*. The default behaviour of XmlSlurper is to ignore namespaces in the sense that when you ask it for a node name without a colon it will find nodes with that local name regardless of namespace. So you may find that simply

```
it.@name
```

finds the attribute you're interested in. If that doesn't work then you'll need to call `declareNamespace` on the object you got back from XmlSlurper, to map a prefix to the namespace URI that corresponds to `model:` in the XML document (look for the `xmlns:model="http://example.com"` or whatever  in the XML)

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse(...).declareNamespace(
    model:"http://example.com")
```

and then `model:name` should work.

Comment: In the model:name case, everything worked with just using it.@name. However, I have another XML which have an xml:lang attribute. Trying to match this attribute using it.@lang does not work. None of the XMLs  contains namespaces. I have tried it['@xml:lang'] with no luck...

Comment: @mamuroc the `xml` prefix refers to the `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace` namespace URI by definition, so try mapping that with `declareNamespace`

Comment: Hrmf, this is weird. when I do: doc.item.findAll {it."@xml:lang"}.each {println "lang: #" + it."@xml:lang".text() + "#", the output is lang: ##. Obviously, the it."@xml:lang" must exists, because I do get the output lang: ##

Comment: Ok, further debug: doc.item.find {!it.'@xml:lang'.isEmpty()}.each {
   println "find: " + it.text()
  } results in empty output. It seems like it either cannot find it.'@xml:lang' or it is empty?

Comment: @mamruoc weird.  If I try `new XmlSlurper().parseText('<root xml:lang="en" foo="bar">hello</root>')` then I can't find a way to extract the `xml:lang` with `@` but calling `attributes()` to get all the attributes as a `Map` tells me that it is in there (under its namespace qualified name `{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang`).  So `it.attributes()['{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang']` should give you what you need.

Comment: Ai, I didn't think of attributes()! Nice, it works now. Weird that we have to use the whole namespace, looks like some kind of bug. Thank you!